# Unable to read property from application.yml using @Value in Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, configuration

My code is unable to read a property value from application.yml in 1 class whereas it is able to read in another class.
Please see my class below:

```
@Component
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class DCCIAccessTokenProvider extends ClientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider{

   @Value("${authCode}")
   private String authorizationCode="";

   @Override
   protected OAuth2AccessToken retrieveToken(AccessTokenRequest request, OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails resource,
        MultiValueMap<String, String> form, HttpHeaders headers) throws OAuth2AccessDeniedException {
       headers.add("Authorization", "Basic "+authorizationCode);
       return super.retrieveToken(request, resource, form, headers);
   }
  }
```

Here, in authorizationCode, I am getting blank while debugging.

I have another class, in which value is getting read properly. Please see below:

```
  @Component
  @EnableConfigurationProperties
  public class SearchBookingProcessor {

  @Autowired
  private OAuth2RestTemplate dcciRestTemplate;

  public OAuth2RestTemplate getDcciRestTemplate() {
    return dcciRestTemplate;
  }

  public void setDcciRestTemplate(OAuth2RestTemplate dcciRestTemplate) {
    this.dcciRestTemplate = dcciRestTemplate;
  }

  @Value("${api.dcci.searchBooking}")
  private String DCCI_API="";

  @Value("${jipcc}")
  private String JIPCC="";

}
```

Here the values are getting read properly.

Please let me know what can be the issue here. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: There is probably a typo. Make sure you wrote `authCode` in `application.yml`. I am marking this question to close as I can not reproduce it on my end.

Comment: Yes I have added authCode in application.yml

Comment: can you show your application.yml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the help. I resolved the problem with the help of my colleague. I was using new object of DCCIAccessTokenProvider, instead of getting it from ApplicationContext and hence it was not able to read the value.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any specific reason for assigning an empty string to the property variable? If that is to set the default value if the property is not available in the file, please try the below line.

```
@Value("${authCode:}")
   private String authorizationCode;
```

Note the ":" after authCode

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: @Prem Kumar I dont think adding a colon ":" will work. Can you see my other class, that is working. I am reading the property in the same way there also.

Comment: Yes. But the point that I am trying to make is around the right way of setting the default value. Also, just a hunch that it could also possibly fix your problem since the issue could be specifically with authCode due to possible special characters in it's value.